# ProgressDialog shows ones time - Android studio

Tags: android, show, progressdialog

I having a problem with a progressDialog on android studio. When the activity is created, a linechart has to be load and a progress dialog is needed to wait until the linechart load finish. It works fine but I need to save a data stream in a file and it takes a time, so I need to shows a progressdialog again but it doesnt show up.

This is the method that I need to show it again.

```
private void writeDataToString(String data, String file_name) throws FileNotFoundException {
    try {
       ProgressDialog progressDialog2 = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progressDialog2.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
        progressDialog2.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressDialog2.show();
        FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput(file_name, MODE_PRIVATE);
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fos);
        osw.write(data);
        osw.flush();
        osw.close();
        progressDialog2.dismiss();

    }
    catch (IOException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

What Im doing wrong? this is the onCreate method.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_records);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progressDialog.setIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
    progressDialog.show();
    // there are a lot of things here but I dont show it
    //......
}
```

Then is this method which cancel the first progressDialog (the one that works). Really, it doenst care but I add it by the way.

```
@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {

    double valor;
    if (recording && takeValue) {
        float[] values = event.values;
        valor = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(values[0], 2) + Math.pow(values[1], 2) + Math.pow(values[2], 2));
        datos.add((float) valor);
    }

    if (takeValue && !(open||savedOpened)) {
      if (flag==149)
          seg=0;

        if (flag < 150)
            flag++;
        else{
           // Here I cancel it
            progressDialog.cancel();

        }
       //.................
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it could be if the OutputStreamWriter runs its write method on another thread (because it’s not a UI requirement), so when it makes the call it continues on with the code causing the closure of the progress bar, you should see if there’s a listener or event that is triggered when the write method is complete and call the dismiss for the progressdialog there

Comment: You re right but I cant find a listener for it. The UI keeps freeze for a while when a big data stream is writing to a file but the progressdialgo doesnt show up.